# Is there a way to keep JavaScript from running on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal here is to stop any attempts at malicious JavaScript code insertion by users who can post content to my website. Assuming my site has no use for JavaScript, is there some tag I can put at the top of each page or some other way to accomplish no possibility of JS running on my page? (a tiny bit of JS at the beginning of the page would be OK as long as it would make sure no more could execute) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No, you cannot force the client browser not to run JavaScript.

Comment: unfortunately not, it is your responsibility to sanitize any user input from malicious intent or otherwise.

Comment: Check for javascript being there, if that works redirect to a page saying you don't allow it. Then expect a massive drop in visitors...

Comment: @Pointy Actually, you can! See my answer below.

Comment: @duskwuff yes you're 100% right :)  I wouldn't rely on that alone of course (as you also note); completely disabling inline scripts can be sort-of problematic for some web app techniques. (Indeed, the whole "I don't need JavaScript at all" thing seems a little suspicious here in 2014.)

Comment: Limiting a site to `script-src 'self'` (or to a more specific origin) is quite feasible, though. Github does it, for instance!

Comment: @Pointy I suppose "I don't need JS" is suspect, but for now that's the plan. I wouldn't be surprised if I needed it later. I suppose my biggest issue is that not all browsers support HTML5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is!

Most modern web browsers support the [Content-Security-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) header, which will allow you to declare in a HTTP header where your site will load certain types of content from, including Javascript code. It is perfectly feasible to declare that your site will not load any Javascript code, nor declare any inline, and this will effectively disable Javascript on your site.

A simple policy that disables all Javascript might be:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'
```

Keep in mind, however, that **not all browsers implement Content-Security-Policy**. You will still need to perform appropriate data sanitization to protect browsers which do not support CSP.

Comment: That won't prevent things like bookmarklets from working on a page, will it? Or JavaScript injected via XSS  weaknesses? *edit* whelp I guess it will :)

Comment: CSP will prevent inline scripts from running as well unless you explicitly permit them. Bookmarklets are a grey area; some may work, some may not.

Comment: @duskwuff Great to know. Thanks. It looks like most people don't know about this and I couldn't easily find this information. I know it's not perfect, but if someone's not using JavaScript, it really could be useful as just one more protection measure, don't you think?

Comment: @EricMartin: Yes, absolutely. Since it's not universally supported, you can't rely on it as your *only* defense against XSS, but it's an excellent backup in case something slips through. Better yet, reporting mode can let you know if something does slip through!

Answer (score 2):

The type of attack you're trying to prevent is called [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). so that's where you'll want to start for learning how to prevent it.

The simplest thing to do is to escape special characters in user input so that users can't post HTML tags such as `<script>`.  That'll work if users shouldn't be able to post HTML at all.  If you need to allow *some* kinds of HTML but not scripts, then you should look into more sophisticated [HTML-sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) techniques.